# Double checked locking: Fences and atomics

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

So I did some reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking and http://preshing.com/20130930/double-checked-locking-is-fixed-in-cpp11/ . I found this code for using it

```
std::atomic<Singleton*> Singleton::m_instance;
std::mutex Singleton::m_mutex;

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() {
    Singleton* tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (tmp == nullptr) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (tmp == nullptr) {
            tmp = new Singleton;
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
            m_instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

and there is one thing that is not clear to me. Does it work differently than following code without fences?

```
std::atomic<Singleton*> Singleton::m_instance;
std::mutex Singleton::m_mutex;

Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() {
    Singleton* tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (tmp == nullptr) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        tmp = m_instance.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
        if (tmp == nullptr) {
            tmp = new Singleton;
            m_instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_release);
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

What I mean if I replace fences with appropriate memory order in load/store, does it work the same?

Comment: Conveniently, when you use C++11 there is **no** need to use any of that! Just use that: `Singleton* Singleton::getInstance(){ static Singleton rc; return &rc; }` Function-local `static` variables are initialized in a thread-safe manner to start with. Note that this comment shall not be considered as an endorsement of singletons: it is an anti-pattern and in my opinion there is no place for singletons, even less so in concurrent code.

Comment: This construction has two disadvantages for me: 1) in Visual Studio 2012 it's not actually thread safe AFAIK 2) you cannot dispose of singleton created in this way before the end of your program

Comment: If you really want to potentially `delete` the object, you *can* use a pointer and allocate it: the initialization is still thread-safe: `static Singleton* rc = new Singleton();`. Whether MSVC++ 2012 initializes function local statics correctly or not I don't know: I prefer not to use broken compilers.

Comment: "I prefer not to use broken compilers" - sadly, not everyone can pick what compiler will they use :/

Comment: If your compiler creates broken code, how can you reason about its behavior? The detailed atomics faffing about you are proposing actually assumes that the compiler gets everything exactly right to even have some hope that the result is correct. That is, if you need to use a broken compiler, you'd need to be a lot more conservative in hoping to have the [obviously buggy] translation do something sensible.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two constructs is explained in a follow-up article on the same site: [Acquire and Release Fences Don't Work the Way You'd Expect](http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/). Basically, the fence guarantees that **all** the atomic stores after the fence will be visible "not before" all the stores before the fence. The store with `memory_order_release` parameter only makes such a guarantee for the stores **to the variable concerned by the store instruction**.

In your example, you only have one atomic, `m_instance`, so the two constructs are functionally equivalent and the one without the fences is probably more performant.